# Calling the Constructor of a Widget though it has no Constructor

Tags: flutter, constructor, widget

I'm fairly new to Flutter. We know that in the `main` function, it has another function called `runApp` which takes a Widget as a parameter which is simply a Class. But it's calling the constructor like `MyApp()` but inside the class, I'm not finding any Constructors but just a `build` function. So how the code is working?

Comment: build is called by the framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MyApp class extends a widget (ex: stateless widget, stateful widget) which is built through the build method. This build method is called by the framework itself.